# Wordpress Ubuntu Database wp_options workaround for developing on localhost but using server database

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, git

I have a ubuntu server with database and files running on it, I commit changes to remote, pull them on my server and want to use my ubuntu database on windows pc, but i can't because of wp_options siteurl and home... how to make this work i want to use the same database as my server and develop on localhost, else i'll have to make the database changes twice...

Comment: In wp-config.php you need to change the database connection from localhost to a link to the database. If this is AWS or AZURE then you will need to create a tunnel in putty (not 100% sure).

Comment: `define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );`

Comment: @Fresz , Wordpress uses the table wp_options to set a siteurl, if I were to change the db_host in wp-config I will never be able to use localhost/project. Instead i will be redirected to the server's ip (set in wp_options).
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#changing-the-url-directly-in-the-database

Comment: ok, I get it. Let me check something.

Comment: Did you try 
`define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );`
`define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );`
in wp-config and change the `DB_HOST` as well. wp-config.php will overwrite the wp_options table

Comment: So did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We need to change the site URL and the DB_HOST in wp-config.php.

Let's make it functional so we don't have to change it every time.

wp-config.php

```
$ip_server = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

if($ip_server == 'YOUR HOST IP ADDRESS') {

  define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

} else {

  define( 'DB_HOST', 'https://url.to.your.db' );
  define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost' );
  define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost' );

}
```

I didn't test it - let me know if you have any issues with it or if I missed anything.